# Can I configure different processes (agile,scrum,etc.) for different teams/boards in one project in AzureDevops?

Tags: azure-devops

I am currently re-designing the structure in AzureDevops for our company.
Previously we created for each component a dedicated project. As some teams worked on mulitple components it was cumbersome to manage that in boards (They are also using AzureDevOps for planning).

So the idea is, to switch to a single project only, use repositories and teams to split up contexts. That is also what microsoft recommends.

The question came up, if (within this one-project-setup) the teams can still decide which process they want to use (scrum, agile, a custom one).

I've invested some time, but it seems it is not possible and that a project is based **on exactly one process.**

Am I right?

I am also asking because ChatGPT told me that this is possible:
"Yes, it is possible to have different processes in one project in Azure DevOps."
But the resources (URLs) it provided went to 404.

Please advise - thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Process templates are defined at the project level, not the individual team level.